# List all constraints in SQL Server that aren't PK/FK

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a quick way to get a list of all the constraints in your database besides the obvious primary/foreign key ones?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server 2005+ (always useful to specify *version* of SQL Server!):

```
SELECT 
  [constraint] = name, 
  [object] = QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id))
    + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id)),
  [definition]
FROM sys.check_constraints
ORDER BY [object], name;

SELECT 
  [constraint] = name,
  [object] = QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id))
    + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id)),
  [definition]
FROM sys.default_constraints
ORDER BY [object], name;
```

If you want to combine them into a single result set:

```
SELECT 
  [constraint] = name, 
  type_desc,
  [object] = QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id))
    + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id)),
  [definition]
FROM sys.check_constraints
UNION ALL
SELECT 
  [constraint] = name,
  type_desc,
  [object] = QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id))
    + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id)),
  [definition]
FROM sys.default_constraints
ORDER BY [object], name;
```